# Schoenfeld residuals - theoretical question

Tags: residuals, cox-model, weibull-distribution, schoenfeld-residuals

I have a doubt about the Schoenfeld residuals that are used to check the Cox proportional hazard model.

The residuals formula is:
$$\hat{r}_{ik}=c_i(x_{ik}-\hat{\bar{x}}_{w_ik})$$
$$\hat{\bar{x}}_{w_ik}=\frac{\sum_{j\in R(t_i)}x_{jk}e^{\vec{x}^{\intercal}_j\vec\beta}}{\sum_{j\in R(t_i)}e^{\vec{x}^{\intercal}_j\vec\beta}}$$

And, in theory, its plot should be on average on close to 0.

To test it I took the Weibull hazard function:
$$h(t)=ba^{-b}t^{b-1}$$
And rewrote it as:
$$h(t)=be^{-b\cdot log(a)}t^{b-1}$$
The Cox proportional hazard model is:
$$h(t,\vec{x},\vec{\beta})=h_0(t)\cdot e^{\vec{\beta}^{\intercal}\vec{x}}$$
That, in this case, becomes:
$$h_0(t)=bt^{b-1}$$
$$\vec\beta=-b$$
$$\vec{x}=log(a)$$

I then tried simulating with MATLAB 1000 uncensored events, randomly split with $a=10$ and $a=20$ and having $b=2$.
I hypothesized my Cox proportional hazard model were able to correctly identify $h_0(t)=bt^{b-1}$ and $\vec\beta=-b$ and computed the theoretical Schoenfeld residuals:
$$\hat{r}_{ik}=log(a_i)-\hat{\bar{x}}_{w_i}$$
$$\hat{\bar{x}}_{w_i}=\frac{\sum_{j\in R(t_i)}log(a_j)e^{-b\cdot log(a_j)}}{\sum_{j\in R(t_i)}e^{-b\cdot log(a_j)}}$$
The result was this:
[image: Theoretical Schoenfeld residuals]
I also tried fitting a Cox proportional hazard model and computing the Schoenfeld residuals automatically (red circles):
[image: Schoenfeld residuals]
The both cases average residuals are not close to 0 at all. I am not sure what I am missing.

I took the Schoenfeld residual formula from:

Applied Survival Analysis: Regression Modelling of Time-to-Event Data, 2nd Edition

https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Applied+Survival+Analysis%3A+Regression+Modeling+of+Time+to+Event+Data%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471754992

Comment: How did you check that the averages of the residuals were  not close to zero? Looking at them isn't very informative, because of the bands in the residuals -- you really need to run a smoother through them to see how the average value varies

Comment: Thank you, you are probably right. I was fooled by the position of the two sets of points in the graph, the upper being way higher above 0 than the lower is low below zero. In facts the lower group is more dense and they probably should balance each other while correctly computing something like a moving average. I am now trying various smoothing methods (moving average, lowess, loess) with different windows, but the line remains very jagged. Do you have by any chance a suggestion on how to correctly smooth the data?

Comment: The `survival::plot.cox.zph` function in R defaults to a spline with 4 degrees of freedom